# Why the element and not the base address got printed?

Tags: c, string, pointers

This is the program I wrote :

```
main()
{
    struct book
           {
               char name[25] ;
               char author[25] ;
               int callno ;
           } ;

     struct book b1 = { "Let us C", "YPK", 101 };
     display(b1.name, b1.author, b1.callno);
 }

void display(char *s, char *t, int n)
{
    printf ("\n%s %s %d", s, t, n);
}
```

Output is

> Let us C YPK 101

as required

Now what we pass to the function `display()` is the base address of the strings `name` and `author` and in the definition of the function , use pointers. So why is the function like `printf("\n%s %s %d", s, t, n)`  and not like `printf("\n%s %s %d", *s, *t, n)`?

The second one does not run . Is not `s` the base address and `*s` the string stored at that address?

Comment: `main()` should be `int main(void)`, and you need `#include <stdio.h>` at the top.

Answer (score 6):

In C, strings are simply blocks of memory that happen to have a null terminator at the end of them. The convention is to refer to strings by `char*` pointers that point at the address of the start of the string. As a result, the library `printf` function is designed so that the `%s` specifier expects you to provide a pointer to the start of the string that should ultimately be printed out.

If you dereference a `char*` pointer, you get back a single `char` representing the initial element of that string. Notice that this isn't the string itself - it's just the first character. If you try to pass `*s` to `printf` where a `%s` specifier is expected, you'll likely crash the program because `printf` will then jump to a memory address whose numeric value is given by the numeric value of the `char` and try to start printing characters it finds there.

Answer (score 3):

The `"%s"` specifier in `printf()` expects a pointer to a string, a string is simply an array of bytes terminated with a special vaule `'\0'` and `printf()` is expecting the *base address* of such array and it also expects the `'\0'` to be at the end, otherwise it will behave incorrectly. You are passing a pointer containing the address to the start of the memory block where the array is sotred, and the `"%s"` specifier will make `printf()` read from the array and output the contents of it to `stdout`.

Passing `*s` to the `"%s"` is undefined behavior as it will interpret the character value `s[0]` as an address and try to read characters from there.

**NOTE 1**: `main()` should return `int`, so it should be one of

```
int main(void);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

**NOTE 2**: Don't put the **end of line** at the begining of a line, it's called **end of line** `'\n'` for a reason, and that reason is that `stdout` is **line** buffered so it requires an `'\n'` to flush the buffer or an explicit `fflush(stdout)`. I don't know whether it's natural to add an `'\n'` at the start of a line if it's meant to end lines, in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) it's even called `std::endl` and is platform dependent.

Answer (score -1):

C has no notion of string besides that: a pointer to a sequence of chars (to the first one). So if you do *a you are getting the first char, not a "string". All C functions that deal with so-called strings expect that kind of pointers.

Comment: A string is not a pointer. A *string* is by definition " a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character". A *pointer to a string* is "a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character".

Comment: @keiththompson: I'm trying to use language that will help a beginner understand the topic, which is notoriously difficult for them. I even quoted the word "string".

Comment: If you want beginners to understand the topic, don't tell them that strings are pointers. They aren't. A string is a sequence of characters; a pointer to a string points to that sequence of characters. That's no more difficult to understand than the idea that a string is a pointer -- and it has the virtue of being correct.

Comment: @KeithThompson Look at the man pages for any of the `strXXX()` functions. E.g. `strcmp()` says *The strcmp() function compares the two strings s1 and s2.* It doesn't say "the two strings pointed to by s1 and s2"

Comment: @Barmar: The Linux man pages are imprecise -- I'd say incorrect. The C standard says "The **`strcmp`** function compares the string pointed to by **`s1`** to the string pointed to by **`s2`**." (N1570 7.24.4.2p2) The Solaris 9 man pages get this right.

Comment: @KeithThompson OK, I'll give you that. But arguing over this terminology detail is probably about as fruitful as trying to correct all the people who use "JSON" to refer to the data structures rather than the string representation.